# linux what locale to set for cp850

Tags: linux, bash, locale, diacritics, codepages

I want to set a locale in a script so that cp850 codepage is used for the string that is handled by the script which will be written in a json-file.

I have found I can set LANG=de_DE.utf8 and I have found that some locales have a .cpXXX in the locale.

Any hint on how to get my umlauts from the string produced by writing to a pipe into the json-file are welcome.

Kind regards,
Jan

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to change the locale, rather try to convert the encoding of your file such that it matches the encoding of your current locale.

On Linux, there is the `iconv` program for converting text from one character encoding to another:

```
$ <your-cp850-coded-file iconv -f CP850 -t UTF-8 >the-new-utf8-encoded-file
```

Of course, you can also use `iconv` in a pipeline.

Comment: Thank you, We will use iconv and see if our problems are solved. Regards, Jan